# How can I place a calculated value in a split shape using a macro and pgfmath?

Tags: pgfmath, tikz-shape

I have a complicated split shape, with multiple nodeparts.  I'd like to enter calculated values in the node parts.

When I try to do it using \pgfmathsetmacro I get an error Undefined control sequence.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12 pt] {article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\newcommand{\splitcalcs}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcOne{ #2 / #1 }
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcTwo{ \calcOne + #1 }
   \nodepart{two}\calcOne
   \nodepart{three}\calcTwo
  }

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (d1)[shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, fill=red!20, draw] at (4,0) 
{Detail 1%
  \splitcalcs{8}{4}
  };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I put the node declaration inside of the command, everything works, so I think it has something to do with the time of the evaluation, but I don't know enough to fix it.

Here's the working (but not desirable) code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12 pt] {article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\newcommand{\splitcalcsb}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcOne{ #2 / #1 }
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcTwo{ \calcOne + #1 }
  \node (d1)[shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, fill=red!20, draw] at (4,0) 
{Detail 1%
   \nodepart{two}\calcOne
   \nodepart{three}\calcTwo
  };
    }

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \splitcalcsb{8}{4}

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `\nodepart` starts a new cell alignment and the assignments done previously are so forgotten.

You can expand the parts you need before `\nodepart` is executed. We need `\noexpand` in front of `\nodepart` in order to avoid its untimely expansion.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt] {article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\newcommand{\splitcalcs}[2]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcOne{ #2 / #1 }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcTwo{ \calcOne + #1 }%
  \expanded{%
    \noexpand\nodepart{two}\calcOne
    \noexpand\nodepart{three}\calcTwo
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (d1)[shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, fill=red!20, draw] at (4,0)
  {Detail \splitcalcs{8}{4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\expanded` needs a fairly recent TeX distribution. You can get the same result with the “traditional” way:

```
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\nodepart{two}\calcOne
    \noexpand\nodepart{three}\calcTwo
  }\x
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I tried ```\noexpand``` by itself, but that did not work.  I did not know about ```\expanded``` to expand the parts when I wanted them to.

Answer (score 1):

For these purposes `xfp` can be handy. (A warning: you cannot replace coordinate computations by `xfp` without being cautious because Ti*k*Z distinguishes between scalars and lengths with units.)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12 pt] {article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\newcommand{\splitcalcs}[2]{%
   \nodepart{two}\fpeval{#2/#1}
   \nodepart{three}\fpeval{1+#2/#1}
  }

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (d1)
  [shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, fill=red!20, draw] 
  at (4,0) 
{Detail 1 \splitcalcs{8}{4}
  };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  This is a potential workaround.  I appreciate your sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, the problem is that `\calcOne` and `\calcTwo` are local to "part one."
If you put `\nodepart{one}` at the beginning, you get the exact same results.  `\nodepart{two}` causes everything after to be placed in "part two" including `\nodepart{three}` (which puts everything after into "part three").

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12 pt] {article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\newcommand{\splitcalcs}[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{ #2 / #1 }%
  \global\let\calcOne=\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{ \calcOne + #1 }%
  \global\let\calcTwo=\pgfmathresult
  \nodepart{two}\calcOne
  \nodepart{three}\calcTwo
  }

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (d1)[shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, fill=red!20, draw] at (4,0) 
{Detail%
  \splitcalcs{8}{4}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how I can make global macros.  This may get me closer to what I need.

Is there a way (using \expandafter or \noexpand) to change the order of expansion and get  the original code to work?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'd prefer `\pgfmathparse{#2/#1}\global\let\calcOne\pgfmathresult`; acting both locally and globally on the same macro may affect the save stack.

Comment: @egreg - I suspect that the local address is removed and replaced by the new global address, just as if I had set the global address to something else.  It obviously works.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It does work, but it impacts on the save stack. TeX is retaining two values at each execution of the macro. Anyway, making the macros global is not the best idea, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg - In any case, using \pgfmathresult saves a step.