# How does the expansion work with nodeparts in pgf multipart nodes?

Tags: expansion, pgfmath, multipart-node

I have had some strange behavior in trying to use calculated values for multipart nodes.  Sometimes values are not available (I get an undefined control sequence error).

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm] {standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\newcommand{\splitcalcsb}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcOne{ #2 / #1 }
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcTwo{ \calcOne + #1 }
  \node (d0)[shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, fill=red!20, draw] at (0,0) 
{Detail 0%
   \nodepart{two}\calcOne
   \nodepart{three}\calcTwo
  };
}

\newcommand{\splitcalcs}[2]{
  \def\calcOne{\fpeval { #2 / #1 }}
  \def\calcTwo{\fpeval{ #2 / #1 + #1 }}
 % Uncomment these two lines to get proper functioning
%  \global\let\calcOne=\calcOne
%  \global\let\calcTwo=\calcTwo
   \nodepart{two}\calcOne
   \nodepart{three}\calcTwo
  }

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

%Uncomment only this line to avoid an error but Detail 1 uses the results of this macro call
%\splitcalcsb{3}{1}

  \node (d1)[shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, fill=red!20, draw] at (4,0) 
{Detail 1%
  \splitcalcs{8}{4}
  };
  
  \splitcalcsb{9}{4}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I run the code as posted, I get an error at line 35:
[image: image of error message]

If I uncomment the `\splitcalcsb{3}{1}` line, the error is no longer triggered, but I get the following image:
[image: image of output with incorrect results]

and the contents of Detail 1 reflect the calculations of the `\splictcalcsb{3}{1}` call rather than the `\splitcalcs{8}{4}`call.

If I uncomment the `\global\let` lines, everything works properly, but I really would like to avoid creating `\global` defintitions.

Does anyone know of a way to (a) use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to define intermediate calculation in a macro, and
(b) use the results of those calculations in  a `\nodepart` call from the same macro without using global variables?

Answer (score 1):

@egreg showed how this should be done in an answer to a similar question.

[How can I place a calculated value in a split shape using a macro and pgfmath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569638/how-can-i-place-a-calculated-value-in-a-split-shape-using-a-macro-and-pgfmath)

Use `\noexpand` and `\expanded`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm] {standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}


\newcommand{\splitcalcs}[2]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcOne{ #2 / #1 }
  \pgfmathsetmacro\calcTwo{ \calcOne + #1 }
   \expanded{%
     \noexpand\nodepart{two} \calcOne
     \noexpand\nodepart{three} \calcTwo
     }%
  }

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (d1)[shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, fill=red!20, draw] at (4,0) 
{Detail 1%
  \splitcalcs{8}{4}
  };
  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the proper output]